# in ruby, how can I know what module is defined as result of a 'load' or 'require'?

Tags: ruby, introspection

In ruby, if I do "require foo", is there a way to subsequently determine the name of the module or modules defined in foo.rb?

For example, say I have a ruby file named foo.rb that looks like this:

```
# foo.rb
module MyModule
    def self.summary
        "this does something useful"
    end
    ...
end
```

In another script, after I do "require foo", how can I determine that I now have a module named MyModule?

Ultimate what I'm after is to be able to do something like this:

```
file = someComputedFileName()
require file
puts "summary of #{file}: #{???::summary}
```

While I could force myself to make module names and file names identical, I'd rather not. I want a bit more freedom in making short filenames but more expressive module names. However, I am guaranteeing to myself that each file will only define a single module (think: plugins).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use [ObjectSpace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/ObjectSpace.html).each_object(Module) to find all defined modules before requiring the file. Then, after you require the file, loop over all defined modules again and see if there are any new ones.

```
require "set"
old_modules = SortedSet.new
ObjectSpace.each_object(Module) {|m| old_modules.add(m) }

file = someComputedFileName()
require file

new_modules = SortedSet.new
ObjectSpace.each_object(Module) {|m| new_modules.add(m) unless old_modules.include?(m) }

puts "summary of #{file}: #{new_modules.to_a.map{|m|m.summary}.join(',')}"
```

That would also let you define more than one module in the file.

Comment: Or just use Sets and examine what's left after new_modules.subtract(old_modules) ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but off the top of my head this seems to work:

```
all_constants = Object.constants
require 'foo'

foo_constants = Object.constants - all_constants
```

foo_constants should give you only the modules, classes or other constants that were defined by foo.rb.

Comment: that works great for top-level modules, but not for sub-modules.

if top-level modules are all you care about, that's a much cleaner solution

Comment: Ah, you're right, I hadn't thought of that. I didn't see your solution before I posted this, but it looks a lot more robust.

Comment: Another problem with this is that if my sub-module requires other modules  those will show up in the results. 

I think my solution will be for each plugin to write their name to a global variable. Not the best solution, but I don't need the best, just one that works.

Comment: Like this solution. Very elegant!